# Erro using genlaguerre in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, physics, scientific-computing

I'm trying to plot the graphs of the following equation in Python.

Solution of the radial differential equation of a 2d quantum ring

[image]

The beta parameter is

[image]

This was my attempt

```
    import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gamma, genlaguerre
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import exp, sqrt

m = 0.067*9.1*10E-31
R = 5E-9
r = np.linspace(0, 20E-9)
#Definição do parâmetro beta

def beta(gama):
    flux = np.linspace(0,1.0)
    beta = sqrt((m-flux)**2+(gama**4)/4)
    return beta

def Rn(n,gama):

    raiz = sqrt((gamma(n+1)/((2**beta(gama)) * gamma(n+beta(gama)+1))))
    eval_g = genlaguerre((n,beta(gama)),((gama * r/R)**2/2))
    exp_g = exp(-((gama * r/R)**2)/4)


    return  (1/R) * raiz * (gama * r/R)**beta(gama) * exp_g * eval_g

sol1 = Rn(0,1.5)
sol2 = Rn(0,2.0)
sol3 = Rn(0,2.5)
sol4 = Rn(0,3.0)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(r/R, sol1, color = 'red', label = '$\gamma$ = 1.5')
ax.plot(r/R, sol2, color = 'green', label = '$\gamma$ = 2.0')
ax.plot(r/R, sol3, color = 'blue', label = '$\gamma$ = 2.5')
ax.plot(r/R, sol4, color = 'black', label = '$\gamma$ = 3.0')
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel('R/r')
ax.set_ylabel('$R_0(r)$')
```

erro using genlaguerre

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Here [the link to the article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074960361300061X)

Comment: In what way are they different? I get 4 different curves which implies to be that **gama** is being passed correctly

Comment: The curves shoud have the peak at the same value of r. But in my plots they are moving away from each other

Comment: how do you know that the peaks should all be in the same place?

Comment: There is a plot in the article with the shapes of the wave functions for n = 0.

Comment: could you edit your opening post to provide a link to the article?

Comment: Done. I added the link

Comment: OK I suspect that you are using `eval_genlaguerre()` incorrectly as no matter what value you put in to evaluate, if you have a polynomial of order 0 you will always get an array of 1s.

Comment: I tried to use just {genlaguerre( )}, but i got an error

Comment: can you edit your post with what you tried & the error you got?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into this topic, but afaics there are at least the following mistakes (I assume setting silently n=0 was on purpose):

1. In opposite to the posted image of the beta function, you added a division by 4 into your function definition.
   Correct version:

```
    def beta(gama): 
        return np.sqrt((m-flux)**2+(gama**4))
```

That's no reason for distributed instead of fixed peaks but I tell what I see here.

2. Product instead of division because of lacking parantheses in definition of amplitude function: 
   Correct version:

```
    def amplitude(gama):
        return np.sqrt(gamma(1)/((2**beta(gama)*gamma(beta(gama)+1))))
```

3. In the definition of Rn function there's the introducing 1/R missing.

---

However, all this unfortunately does not change the peaks to happen at equal x positions...

Comment: I verified all the calculations myself to be sure that the author of the article was right. And there is really a division by four. I believe there was a typo

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what you mean. You posted some equations and some code which should be the python implementation. And imo there are three mistakes in the python code against those formulas. If the division by 4 is sth you already know about and which you're ok with, then why don't you tell this in your question? And if the other two differences are also ok, then... well, let's say I can't help

Comment: I implemented the changes you suggested on the code and, as you said, they did not produced any changes in the graphs.
Well, since there is no syntax errors, and I don't have almost any background on programming, was trying to get some help with the way that code is implemented. gama and beta are parameters of the wave function. Also, gama is inside beta, and I think that I'm not making Python "understand" this

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! The radial wave function of the article is wrong! I made the calculations and found the correct answer. The following code is correct

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import genlaguerre, gamma
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = 0 # magnetic number
flux = 0  # Phi in eqn 8
R = 5  # nm
r = np.linspace(0, 6 * R)

rho = r / R

def R0(n, gama):
    beta = np.sqrt((m - flux)**2 + gama**4/4)
    return (gama/R*
            np.sqrt(gamma(n+ 1) / ( 2**beta * gamma(n + beta + 1))) *
            (gama * rho)**beta *
            np.exp(-gama**2 * rho**2 / 4) *
            genlaguerre(n, beta)(gama**2 * rho**2 / 2))


sol1 = R0(0, 1.5)
sol2 = R0(0, 2.0)
sol3 = R0(0, 2.5)
sol4 = R0(0, 3.0)

plt.plot(rho, sol1, rho, sol2, rho, sol3, rho, sol4)
plt.legend(['$\gamma = 1.5$', '$\gamma = 2$', '$\gamma = 2.5$', '$\gamma = 3$'])
plt.ylabel('$R_{0}(r)$')
plt.xlabel('$r/R$')
plt.show()
```